# Jquery get height of auto height element

Tags: jquery, height

Is there any way to return the height of an element that is already set to auto? I just get 0 when I call $("#element").height();

Here is the jquery code. The **img.height()** return 0 therefore the end result is off.

```
img.css({top: (img.parent().height() - img.height()) /2, left: (img.parent().outerWidth() - img.outerWidth()) / 2});
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="exploreImage" class="virtual-room-large" style="width: 288px; height: auto; top: 185px; left: 89px; ">
```

Comment: Usually, if `height()` returns 0, the element's height *is* 0. Can you show the HTML of the element and what is in it, and the full jQuery code?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Did you try [`$("#element").outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/)? It gets the computed height rather than the explicitly set height.

Comment: If this doesn't work, why is it the accepted answer?

Comment: `outerHeight` also returns "0".

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and found the solution here: 
http://www.fortwaynewebdevelopment.com/jquery-width-or-height-always-returns-0-fix/

When I'm using jQuery, I like to stick to it as much as I can for consistency's sake.

Actually both solutions - using window.load(){} or $("*my element*").load(){} worked beautifully for me so I hope this can help you out as well or anyone else finding this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately when I posted this 6 years ago, I didn't quite yet get the idea posting the full solution here to prevent link rot.

Comment: is it possible to modify your answer and include the code that used to be in the linked page?

Comment: I no longer have access to that project's code so I don't believe I'd be able to. If I get some time I'll try to re-solution this this here.

Answer (score 3):

I have found a workaround for doing a transition with ease-in AND ease-out. This workaround needs the "jump" of the element:

```
var elementselector = "#elementtoscroll";
$(elementselector ).css("height", "auto");
var elemheight = $(elementselector).css("height");
$(elementselector).css("height", "0");
$(elementselector).css("height", elemheight);
```

This way, javascript gets the height - I know it's not a beuatiful way, but it works. This is important for example for the ease-out effect.

EDIT: It should be said, that this is just possible with CSS3 and a CSS-Style like this:

```
#panel{
    background-color: #FF00FF;
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    transition: all 300ms ease-in-out;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please check you try to get height when DOM is ready, that is to say in the window.onload function.

In case your div element is empty and height is auto, it will return 0. So your div is likely to be empty before full page is loaded.

For example : I want to remember initial heights for my .elementDiv divs :

```
var initialHeight = [];
window.onload = function() {
$('.elementDiv').each(function(i) {
  initialHeight[i]=$(this).height();
  });
  // then use it
  }
```

When not in the onload function, the heights I get are all 0.

I hope this was the reason, because I don't see anything else..

Answer (score 0):

You can try Window.getComputedStyle();

It will return the a set of computed style, (if ever the style property is not defined e.g. auto)

```
var elem1 = document.getElementById("elemId");
var style = window.getComputedStyle(elem1);
```

You can then say

```
var computedHeight = style.height;
```

for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: It returns "auto" for me on Chrome :(.

Comment: @VeritatisCupitor you can try `document.getElementsById("elemId").getBoundingClientRect()`

then check the result there it should give you values.
then you can get the height based on this. more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Answer (score -1):

I think offsetHeight or clientHeight or scrollHeight can solve it. for example:

```
img.parent()[0].offsetHeight
```

or

```
img.parent()[0].scrollHeight
```

Different between these 3 methods can see here:

- http://jsfiddle.net/shibualexis/yVhgM/3/
- [What is offsetHeight, clientHeight, scrollHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight)

Comment: Please explain the differences (and implications of each method) in the answer, rather than linking to external sources.

Comment: I do think so. but the 2 links explain well.

Comment: Always good to include context for the content in your links. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer particularly the reasons behind adding the important part of the linked content.