# Parallax Video Progess Scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, video, scroll, parallax

I'm looking to create a **video parallax background**, but I want that the progress of the video corresponds to where I am on my webpage.

For example :

- When im on the top of the page the video is at 0 seconds,
- in the middle at 50% of its total runtime
- and finishes only when I reach the bottom of the page.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

**You have to break down the big problem into smaller problems.**

First, you need to [get your video's duration](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp) :

```
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");
duration = vid.duration;
```

Next, you need to get the [scroll amount in percentage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28677335/get-percentage-of-scroll-position)

```
function getVerticalScrollPercentage (elm) {
  var p = elm.parentNode
  return (elm.scrollTop || p.scrollTop) / (p.scrollHeight - p.clientHeight ) * 100
}
```

Next, you need to [dynamically set your video's currentTime](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp) (in seconds), you can do it this way :

```
vid.currentTime = duration * percentage / 100;
```

And finally, you need to set the currentTime again, whenever the scroll amount changes. That is achieved by using an event listener, on the `body` for example.

```
object.addEventListener("scroll", myScript);
```

Now put it all together :)

Comment: hm... seems i dont really get it :D i tried it in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Pinnhead1987/efq6awd1/61/ but it throws me an ReferenceError

Comment: I gave you an example of how it works, but you still need to rename `myScript` to the actual name of the script and object to the container that scrolls.

Comment: Here's an example put together, but you still need to tweak some values. https://jsfiddle.net/8kLvto70/35/