# Overflow check not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

https://jsfiddle.net/basickarl/apts370w/1/

I'm expecting the `checkOverflow` function to return `true` in this case.

HTML:

```
<div style="float:right;">
  <div id="z">
    <div id="txt">
      345345345345345345345345345345345
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
console.log(checkOverflow(document.getElementById('z')));

function checkOverflow(el) {

  var curOverflow = el.style.overflow;

  if (!curOverflow || curOverflow === 'visible')
    el.style.overflow = 'hidden';

  var isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;

  el.style.overflow = curOverflow;

  return isOverflowing;
};
```

CSS:

```
div#z {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div#txt {
  background: lightblue;
  float: right;
}
```

Any idea why the `console.log` of the function returns `true` here?

Comment: Any answer actually answered your question?

Answer (score 2):

`scrollHeight` and `scrollWidth` correspond to the actual `clientHeight` and `clientWdith` + the hidden height or width. Since `div#txt` is floated to the right, it doesn't overflow.

You should have a look at the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) and at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight) as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `#txt` is floated to the right, so it overflows towards the left.

But with the default left-to-right direction it's not possible to scroll towards the left.

However, you can if you use a right-to-left direction

```css
#z { direction: rtl; }
```

```js
function checkOverflow(el) {
  var curOverflow = el.style.overflow;
  if (!curOverflow || curOverflow === 'visible')
    el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  var isOverflowing = el.clientWidth < el.scrollWidth || el.clientHeight < el.scrollHeight;
  el.style.overflow = curOverflow;
  return isOverflowing;
}
console.log(checkOverflow(document.getElementById('z')));
```

```css
div#z {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
  direction: rtl;
}
div#txt {
  background: lightblue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:right;">
  <div id="z">
    <div id="txt">
      345345345345345345345345345345345
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, if then content overflows towards the right (e.g. you change to `float: left`), you will have the same problem.

If you want a more general approach, you can use `getBoundingClientRect`:

```js
var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
var isOverflowing = [].every.call(el.children, function(child) {
  var childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
  return childRect.left < rect.left
    || childRect.right > rect.right
    || childRect.top < rect.top
    || childRect.bottom > rect.bottom;
});
```

```js
function checkOverflow(el) {
  var curOverflow = getComputedStyle(el).overflow;
  if (!curOverflow || curOverflow === 'visible')
    el.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  var isOverflowing = [].every.call(el.children, function(child) {
    var childRect = child.getBoundingClientRect();
    return childRect.left < rect.left
      || childRect.right > rect.right
      || childRect.top < rect.top
      || childRect.bottom > rect.bottom;
  });
  el.style.overflow = curOverflow;
  return isOverflowing;
}
console.log(checkOverflow(document.getElementById('z')));
```

```css
div#z {
  position: relative;
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: auto;
}
div#txt {
  background: lightblue;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div style="float:right;">
  <div id="z">
    <div id="txt">
      345345345345345345345345345345345
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

https://jsfiddle.net/apts370w/3/

The problem is that is not a inline element, if you change to span tag it works

I change this too

```
el.offsetWidth //instead of clientWidth
```

Comment: This only "works" because the selector `div#txt` no longer applies, and then it's no longer floated to the right.

Comment: If you put the float again, it works again, because the tag changes to <span>. Check it!

Comment: See the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/apts370w/7/ . So you are wrong in this case. With inline elements this works perfectly