# Incorrect height of div returned by JS

Tags: javascript

```
var div = document.getElementById('foo');
console.log(div);
console.log(div.scrollHeight);
```

When I click on the DOM of div returned by the first log in the console, its scrollHeight is x, while the second log prints out y; x != y.

Comment: content is still loading/rendering?

Comment: But I'm logging the div before div.scrollheight and in the div it's the correct value. Maybe it still is the case, how to fix it in pure javascript/angularjs?

Comment: If you just want to get the height of an element you could use     "div.clientHeight" which should give you exactly that.

Comment: So do you read the value onload, document ready, when it renders?

Comment: You tagged your question as "angularjs". Can you add the more context to your question by attaching more relevant portions from your code - view, controller, css, ...? Maybe you have a CSS3 transition/animation that happens on focus (:focus pseudo-class for example). And maybe that transition/animation grows for a duration :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight

Comment: @epascarello same problem here, your comment leads me to try a dirty `setTimeout()` and infact it solved but I need a more solid solution. All my app runs after document ready (this mechanism to be precise: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63928131/1252920) so it had work... I'm confused now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get height of a div try-

**1. JavaScript:**

```
var clientHeight = document.getElementById('divId').clientHeight;
```

**or**

```
var offsetHeight = document.getElementById('divId').offsetHeight;
```

**2. jQuery:**

```
var height= $("#divId").height();
```

**3. vanilla JS:**

```
var clientHeight =  document.querySelector('#divId').clientHeight;
```

**or**

```
var offsetHeight = document.querySelector('#divId').offsetHeight;
```

Comment: Why depend on jQuery when vanilla JS can do the same?

Comment: @McSim down vote it's ok but why? I give 3 options JS and jQuery. If u think it's not enough please write a new answer. I want to learn more. honestly speck i dont know vanilla JS.I only know JS and jQuery.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651923/when-to-use-vanilla-javascript-vs-jquery

Comment: Yeah, you're right, this probably doesn't deserve a downvote (removed it) as it answers the question and part of it actually is vanilla JS (JS with no frameworks or libraries). It just struck me, that the first sentence in the answer about JS says "use jQuery" for something, that doesn't require jQuery. jQuery might be useful in some cases, but in 2019, with quite powerful JS on itself, it just becomes an unnecessary dependency on such a large library. `document.querySelector()` does `$()` and `clientHeight`/`offsetHeight`/`scrollHeight` targets the specific "kind of height" you need.

Comment: Ah, sry I can't upvote it back until your answer gets edited. That's a weird rule of StackOverflow...

Comment: Yeah, the upvote works now. But "vanilla JS" is just a term that describes "clean" JS without any large libraries or frameworks, it's the same as just "JS". So `querySelector` works in JS.

Answer (score 1):

> What I can see, here I'm getting perfect height. Can you please give your code that you have tried so far?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>

</head>
<body>
 <div id="foo">HELLO WORLD!!!</div>
 <script type="text/javascript">


 var div= document.getElementById('foo');
 console.log(div);
 console.log(div.scrollHeight);
 console.log(div.clientHeight);
 console.log(div.offsetHeight);
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .load to wait till that element is loaded in the dom

```
$('#foo').load(function(){
  // your code to find height
  $('#foo').height()
  });
```