# The div doesn't get smaller when i try to animate it with setTimeout()?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
div.addEventListener('click', () => {
        for (let i=1; i<3000; i++) {
          setTimeout(() => {

            let style = div.clientHeight-1;

            style = style + 'px'; 
            div.style.height = style;

          },i)
        }

    })
```

Why doesn't this code work? I have a div element 500x500 and I try to animate it's height. When I set `let style = div.clientHeight - 2;` or to a number bigger than 2, it works, but it doesn't work for 1. What is the problem, and how do I animate the height with JS properly?

Comment: Drop the `for` and the `setTimeout`. Use `setInterval` instead.

Comment: You can do this with css too. A lot easier.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I know how to do it with css transition but I want to do it with Javascript, this is more like an exercise. But I can't find out why the code doesn't work. Have you any idea?

Comment: I'll have look.

Comment: Check this similar post <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44467909/animating-max-height-with-pure-js>. Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 6):

You could do this using minimal Javascript and use CSS instead.

Add a `transition: height 3s;` to your `<div>` and create a class that changes the height of your `<div>`.

After a click on it, just add the class in Javascript:

```js
let div = document.querySelector('div');

div.addEventListener('click', () => {
  div.classList.add('clicked');
})
```

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  transition: height 3s;
}

div.clicked{
  height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```