# How to Convert String to Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of code:

`($(".contact-msg-inpt").prop("scrollHeight"))`

and I'm trying to figure out how can I add a number, say 5 or 8, or 10 or whatever to this value, but in one line?

I tried this one, but it didn't work:

`parseInt("(($(".contact-msg-inpt").prop("scrollHeight"))", 10)`

Comment: Number($(".contact-msg-inpt").prop("scrollHeight")) + X

Comment: Thank you all! Very, very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by doing :

```
var result = parseInt($(".contact-msg-inpt").prop("scrollHeight"))+10;
```

You have to parse the value first then add the number to it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Sletheren!

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you are literally trying to parse the string `($(".contact-msg-inpt").prop("scrollHeight"))` as an int. And furthermore this string is incorrect because of the quotes inside.

Loose the quotes at the beginning and end. The extra parantheses are not needed as well.

```
parseInt($(".contact-msg-inpt").prop("scrollHeight"), 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

scrollHeight is a readonly property, you can't change it, change the element height / padding / using css or styles.

see this answer here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675563/1243058