# Find document height using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to find out the loaded document height. I'm using this :

document.body.scrollHeight;

It works in certain websites, but others no. It will work in stackoverflow for instance, but not on youtube (it will return zero). Why ? How can i get the height in cases like youtube ?

By the way, i'm using Google Chrome Devtools to test.

Thanks

Comment: Returns 'undefined' on youtube @ScottMarcus

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight