# HTML - check if content will fit into fix-sized div

Tags: html, css

I need to print some pages. I generate div´s for every page with fixed size, so I can control the content of every page and no content will appear on a wrong page.

So here is my problem: Sometimes the content of the first page is larger than the div. I need to check if it fit´s into the div. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the scrollHeight vs clientHeight?

> scrollHeight: ENTIRE  content & padding (visible or not) Height of all
>   content + paddings, despite of height of the element.
>
> clientHeight: VISIBLE content & padding Only visible height: content
>   portion limited by explicitly defined height of the element.

Great explanation here: [What is offsetHeight, clientHeight, scrollHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight)

[image] [image]

*More info:*

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight