# Why do scrollHeight, clientHeight & offsetHeight all return the same value?

Tags: javascript, dom

According to [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22675563/7238242) `scrollHeight`, `clientHeight` and `offsetHeight` all return different values.

**scrollHeight**

> is a measurement of the height of an element's content including
>   content not visible on the screen due to overflow

**clientHeight**

> returns the inner height of an element in pixels, including padding
>   but not the horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin

**offsetHeight**

> is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element
>   vertical padding, the element horizontal scrollbar (if present, if
>   rendered) and the element CSS height.

However when I tested these properties they returned identical values.  This was true in Chrome, Firefox and IE.  I included my test code for all 3 methods below.  What am I doing wrong?  Shouldn't they return different values?

**scrollHeight value**

```js
"use strict"

console.log(document.querySelector('.testDiv').scrollHeight);
```

```css
.testDiv {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque quam a ultricies eleifend. Duis pharetra mi sit amet est tempor auctor. Vestibulum pellentesque metus at blandit pharetra. Cras sodales sem eu nisl interdum, placerat ornare nisi malesuada. Nam at bibendum nunc, eu feugiat neque. Sed quis lacus in lacus ornare ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan libero eget libero iaculis varius.

 Nulla eget orci dolor. Curabitur varius volutpat arcu, sed porta erat faucibus vitae. Nulla vitae consequat tortor. Sed ornare, elit sit amet tempus tincidunt, leo arcu malesuada elit, iaculis aliquam neque tortor a nisi. Aliquam placerat faucibus tortor, et interdum massa tristique vitae. Maecenas commodo lobortis libero ac placerat. Nam tincidunt augue non sollicitudin iaculis. Etiam consectetur libero non neque varius efficitur. Maecenas id tortor ipsum.
            
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ut quam et eros ullamcorper posuere nec vitae sapien. Cras id leo placerat, porttitor felis vel, accumsan mauris. Nullam eget mauris vitae libero tincidunt dictum non et sem. Integer ipsum orci, blandit sit amet porta sollicitudin, interdum id nisl. Duis ac nulla mauris. Fusce dictum porttitor dolor vel viverra. Integer tempus nisi sed enim semper tristique. Maecenas feugiat, lectus ac viverra semper, orci libero lobortis urna, placerat accumsan nulla quam non libero. Proin ex ante, vehicula quis aliquam id, consectetur efficitur orci. Quisque nisi quam, volutpat at convallis condimentum, sodales eget magna.
            
Integer accumsan vehicula sagittis. Donec sed malesuada mauris, at sagittis odio. Donec facilisis orci at sapien gravida, ac cursus dolor consectetur. Integer gravida at elit non eleifend. Fusce maximus mauris vitae lectus venenatis, id volutpat mauris viverra. Etiam libero urna, porttitor ut neque feugiat, maximus sollicitudin lorem. Morbi convallis ultrices sem quis rutrum. Aenean varius risus non justo accumsan posuere. Nam egestas quis leo quis suscipit. Morbi ac quam quam. Aliquam erat volutpat.
            
Morbi eget dui ut mauris bibendum laoreet vitae sed nunc. Duis dignissim, lacus ornare condimentum semper, est elit fringilla nisi, ac pharetra risus diam eu sem. Curabitur eget urna nec ex pharetra lacinia. Proin eu metus felis. Nunc luctus sem eget nulla volutpat vestibulum. Phasellus ut interdum velit, sit amet vestibulum tortor. Donec pretium euismod pharetra. Donec consequat in sem quis consectetur. Proin tempor nulla nibh, sed porta dolor hendrerit a. Nam tincidunt nisl eget leo ornare, non fringilla nulla viverra. Suspendisse volutpat est vel tellus gravida tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque quam a ultricies eleifend. Duis pharetra mi sit amet est tempor auctor. Vestibulum pellentesque metus at blandit pharetra. Cras sodales sem eu nisl interdum, placerat ornare nisi malesuada. Nam at bibendum nunc, eu feugiat neque. Sed quis lacus in lacus ornare ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan libero eget libero iaculis varius.

Nulla eget orci dolor. Curabitur varius volutpat arcu, sed porta erat faucibus vitae. Nulla vitae consequat tortor. Sed ornare, elit sit amet tempus tincidunt, leo arcu malesuada elit, iaculis aliquam neque tortor a nisi. Aliquam placerat faucibus tortor, et interdum massa tristique vitae. Maecenas commodo lobortis libero ac placerat. Nam tincidunt augue non sollicitudin iaculis. Etiam consectetur libero non neque varius efficitur. Maecenas id tortor ipsum.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ut quam et eros ullamcorper posuere nec vitae sapien. Cras id leo placerat, porttitor felis vel, accumsan mauris. Nullam eget mauris vitae libero tincidunt dictum non et sem. Integer ipsum orci, blandit sit amet porta sollicitudin, interdum id nisl. Duis ac nulla mauris. Fusce dictum porttitor dolor vel viverra. Integer tempus nisi sed enim semper tristique. Maecenas feugiat, lectus ac viverra semper, orci libero lobortis urna, placerat accumsan nulla quam non libero. Proin ex ante, vehicula quis aliquam id, consectetur efficitur orci. Quisque nisi quam, volutpat at convallis condimentum, sodales eget magna.

</div>
```

**clientHeight value**

```js
"use strict"

console.log(document.querySelector('.testDiv').clientHeight);
```

```css
.testDiv {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque quam a ultricies eleifend. Duis pharetra mi sit amet est tempor auctor. Vestibulum pellentesque metus at blandit pharetra. Cras sodales sem eu nisl interdum, placerat ornare nisi malesuada. Nam at bibendum nunc, eu feugiat neque. Sed quis lacus in lacus ornare ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan libero eget libero iaculis varius.

 Nulla eget orci dolor. Curabitur varius volutpat arcu, sed porta erat faucibus vitae. Nulla vitae consequat tortor. Sed ornare, elit sit amet tempus tincidunt, leo arcu malesuada elit, iaculis aliquam neque tortor a nisi. Aliquam placerat faucibus tortor, et interdum massa tristique vitae. Maecenas commodo lobortis libero ac placerat. Nam tincidunt augue non sollicitudin iaculis. Etiam consectetur libero non neque varius efficitur. Maecenas id tortor ipsum.
            
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ut quam et eros ullamcorper posuere nec vitae sapien. Cras id leo placerat, porttitor felis vel, accumsan mauris. Nullam eget mauris vitae libero tincidunt dictum non et sem. Integer ipsum orci, blandit sit amet porta sollicitudin, interdum id nisl. Duis ac nulla mauris. Fusce dictum porttitor dolor vel viverra. Integer tempus nisi sed enim semper tristique. Maecenas feugiat, lectus ac viverra semper, orci libero lobortis urna, placerat accumsan nulla quam non libero. Proin ex ante, vehicula quis aliquam id, consectetur efficitur orci. Quisque nisi quam, volutpat at convallis condimentum, sodales eget magna.
            
Integer accumsan vehicula sagittis. Donec sed malesuada mauris, at sagittis odio. Donec facilisis orci at sapien gravida, ac cursus dolor consectetur. Integer gravida at elit non eleifend. Fusce maximus mauris vitae lectus venenatis, id volutpat mauris viverra. Etiam libero urna, porttitor ut neque feugiat, maximus sollicitudin lorem. Morbi convallis ultrices sem quis rutrum. Aenean varius risus non justo accumsan posuere. Nam egestas quis leo quis suscipit. Morbi ac quam quam. Aliquam erat volutpat.
            
Morbi eget dui ut mauris bibendum laoreet vitae sed nunc. Duis dignissim, lacus ornare condimentum semper, est elit fringilla nisi, ac pharetra risus diam eu sem. Curabitur eget urna nec ex pharetra lacinia. Proin eu metus felis. Nunc luctus sem eget nulla volutpat vestibulum. Phasellus ut interdum velit, sit amet vestibulum tortor. Donec pretium euismod pharetra. Donec consequat in sem quis consectetur. Proin tempor nulla nibh, sed porta dolor hendrerit a. Nam tincidunt nisl eget leo ornare, non fringilla nulla viverra. Suspendisse volutpat est vel tellus gravida tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque quam a ultricies eleifend. Duis pharetra mi sit amet est tempor auctor. Vestibulum pellentesque metus at blandit pharetra. Cras sodales sem eu nisl interdum, placerat ornare nisi malesuada. Nam at bibendum nunc, eu feugiat neque. Sed quis lacus in lacus ornare ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan libero eget libero iaculis varius.

Nulla eget orci dolor. Curabitur varius volutpat arcu, sed porta erat faucibus vitae. Nulla vitae consequat tortor. Sed ornare, elit sit amet tempus tincidunt, leo arcu malesuada elit, iaculis aliquam neque tortor a nisi. Aliquam placerat faucibus tortor, et interdum massa tristique vitae. Maecenas commodo lobortis libero ac placerat. Nam tincidunt augue non sollicitudin iaculis. Etiam consectetur libero non neque varius efficitur. Maecenas id tortor ipsum.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ut quam et eros ullamcorper posuere nec vitae sapien. Cras id leo placerat, porttitor felis vel, accumsan mauris. Nullam eget mauris vitae libero tincidunt dictum non et sem. Integer ipsum orci, blandit sit amet porta sollicitudin, interdum id nisl. Duis ac nulla mauris. Fusce dictum porttitor dolor vel viverra. Integer tempus nisi sed enim semper tristique. Maecenas feugiat, lectus ac viverra semper, orci libero lobortis urna, placerat accumsan nulla quam non libero. Proin ex ante, vehicula quis aliquam id, consectetur efficitur orci. Quisque nisi quam, volutpat at convallis condimentum, sodales eget magna.

</div>
```

**offsetHeight value**

```js
"use strict"

console.log(document.querySelector('.testDiv').offsetHeight);
```

```css
.testDiv {
    background-color: red;
    padding: 10px
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque quam a ultricies eleifend. Duis pharetra mi sit amet est tempor auctor. Vestibulum pellentesque metus at blandit pharetra. Cras sodales sem eu nisl interdum, placerat ornare nisi malesuada. Nam at bibendum nunc, eu feugiat neque. Sed quis lacus in lacus ornare ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan libero eget libero iaculis varius.

 Nulla eget orci dolor. Curabitur varius volutpat arcu, sed porta erat faucibus vitae. Nulla vitae consequat tortor. Sed ornare, elit sit amet tempus tincidunt, leo arcu malesuada elit, iaculis aliquam neque tortor a nisi. Aliquam placerat faucibus tortor, et interdum massa tristique vitae. Maecenas commodo lobortis libero ac placerat. Nam tincidunt augue non sollicitudin iaculis. Etiam consectetur libero non neque varius efficitur. Maecenas id tortor ipsum.
            
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ut quam et eros ullamcorper posuere nec vitae sapien. Cras id leo placerat, porttitor felis vel, accumsan mauris. Nullam eget mauris vitae libero tincidunt dictum non et sem. Integer ipsum orci, blandit sit amet porta sollicitudin, interdum id nisl. Duis ac nulla mauris. Fusce dictum porttitor dolor vel viverra. Integer tempus nisi sed enim semper tristique. Maecenas feugiat, lectus ac viverra semper, orci libero lobortis urna, placerat accumsan nulla quam non libero. Proin ex ante, vehicula quis aliquam id, consectetur efficitur orci. Quisque nisi quam, volutpat at convallis condimentum, sodales eget magna.
            
Integer accumsan vehicula sagittis. Donec sed malesuada mauris, at sagittis odio. Donec facilisis orci at sapien gravida, ac cursus dolor consectetur. Integer gravida at elit non eleifend. Fusce maximus mauris vitae lectus venenatis, id volutpat mauris viverra. Etiam libero urna, porttitor ut neque feugiat, maximus sollicitudin lorem. Morbi convallis ultrices sem quis rutrum. Aenean varius risus non justo accumsan posuere. Nam egestas quis leo quis suscipit. Morbi ac quam quam. Aliquam erat volutpat.
            
Morbi eget dui ut mauris bibendum laoreet vitae sed nunc. Duis dignissim, lacus ornare condimentum semper, est elit fringilla nisi, ac pharetra risus diam eu sem. Curabitur eget urna nec ex pharetra lacinia. Proin eu metus felis. Nunc luctus sem eget nulla volutpat vestibulum. Phasellus ut interdum velit, sit amet vestibulum tortor. Donec pretium euismod pharetra. Donec consequat in sem quis consectetur. Proin tempor nulla nibh, sed porta dolor hendrerit a. Nam tincidunt nisl eget leo ornare, non fringilla nulla viverra. Suspendisse volutpat est vel tellus gravida tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque quam a ultricies eleifend. Duis pharetra mi sit amet est tempor auctor. Vestibulum pellentesque metus at blandit pharetra. Cras sodales sem eu nisl interdum, placerat ornare nisi malesuada. Nam at bibendum nunc, eu feugiat neque. Sed quis lacus in lacus ornare ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan libero eget libero iaculis varius.

Nulla eget orci dolor. Curabitur varius volutpat arcu, sed porta erat faucibus vitae. Nulla vitae consequat tortor. Sed ornare, elit sit amet tempus tincidunt, leo arcu malesuada elit, iaculis aliquam neque tortor a nisi. Aliquam placerat faucibus tortor, et interdum massa tristique vitae. Maecenas commodo lobortis libero ac placerat. Nam tincidunt augue non sollicitudin iaculis. Etiam consectetur libero non neque varius efficitur. Maecenas id tortor ipsum.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ut quam et eros ullamcorper posuere nec vitae sapien. Cras id leo placerat, porttitor felis vel, accumsan mauris. Nullam eget mauris vitae libero tincidunt dictum non et sem. Integer ipsum orci, blandit sit amet porta sollicitudin, interdum id nisl. Duis ac nulla mauris. Fusce dictum porttitor dolor vel viverra. Integer tempus nisi sed enim semper tristique. Maecenas feugiat, lectus ac viverra semper, orci libero lobortis urna, placerat accumsan nulla quam non libero. Proin ex ante, vehicula quis aliquam id, consectetur efficitur orci. Quisque nisi quam, volutpat at convallis condimentum, sodales eget magna.

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example the div itself doesn't scroll, the scroll you see belongs to the body, that's why you're seeing the same results...try this:

```js
const el = document.querySelector('.testDiv');
console.log('clientHeight:', el.clientHeight);
console.log('scrollHeight:', el.scrollHeight);
console.log('offsetHeight:', el.offsetHeight);
```

```css
.testDiv {
    background-color: red;
    border: 50px solid yellow;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="testDiv">

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque quam a ultricies eleifend. Duis pharetra mi sit amet est tempor auctor. Vestibulum pellentesque metus at blandit pharetra. Cras sodales sem eu nisl interdum, placerat ornare nisi malesuada. Nam at bibendum nunc, eu feugiat neque. Sed quis lacus in lacus ornare ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan libero eget libero iaculis varius.

 Nulla eget orci dolor. Curabitur varius volutpat arcu, sed porta erat faucibus vitae. Nulla vitae consequat tortor. Sed ornare, elit sit amet tempus tincidunt, leo arcu malesuada elit, iaculis aliquam neque tortor a nisi. Aliquam placerat faucibus tortor, et interdum massa tristique vitae. Maecenas commodo lobortis libero ac placerat. Nam tincidunt augue non sollicitudin iaculis. Etiam consectetur libero non neque varius efficitur. Maecenas id tortor ipsum.
            
In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ut quam et eros ullamcorper posuere nec vitae sapien. Cras id leo placerat, porttitor felis vel, accumsan mauris. Nullam eget mauris vitae libero tincidunt dictum non et sem. Integer ipsum orci, blandit sit amet porta sollicitudin, interdum id nisl. Duis ac nulla mauris. Fusce dictum porttitor dolor vel viverra. Integer tempus nisi sed enim semper tristique. Maecenas feugiat, lectus ac viverra semper, orci libero lobortis urna, placerat accumsan nulla quam non libero. Proin ex ante, vehicula quis aliquam id, consectetur efficitur orci. Quisque nisi quam, volutpat at convallis condimentum, sodales eget magna.
            
Integer accumsan vehicula sagittis. Donec sed malesuada mauris, at sagittis odio. Donec facilisis orci at sapien gravida, ac cursus dolor consectetur. Integer gravida at elit non eleifend. Fusce maximus mauris vitae lectus venenatis, id volutpat mauris viverra. Etiam libero urna, porttitor ut neque feugiat, maximus sollicitudin lorem. Morbi convallis ultrices sem quis rutrum. Aenean varius risus non justo accumsan posuere. Nam egestas quis leo quis suscipit. Morbi ac quam quam. Aliquam erat volutpat.
            
Morbi eget dui ut mauris bibendum laoreet vitae sed nunc. Duis dignissim, lacus ornare condimentum semper, est elit fringilla nisi, ac pharetra risus diam eu sem. Curabitur eget urna nec ex pharetra lacinia. Proin eu metus felis. Nunc luctus sem eget nulla volutpat vestibulum. Phasellus ut interdum velit, sit amet vestibulum tortor. Donec pretium euismod pharetra. Donec consequat in sem quis consectetur. Proin tempor nulla nibh, sed porta dolor hendrerit a. Nam tincidunt nisl eget leo ornare, non fringilla nulla viverra. Suspendisse volutpat est vel tellus gravida tempor.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse scelerisque quam a ultricies eleifend. Duis pharetra mi sit amet est tempor auctor. Vestibulum pellentesque metus at blandit pharetra. Cras sodales sem eu nisl interdum, placerat ornare nisi malesuada. Nam at bibendum nunc, eu feugiat neque. Sed quis lacus in lacus ornare ultricies. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris accumsan libero eget libero iaculis varius.

Nulla eget orci dolor. Curabitur varius volutpat arcu, sed porta erat faucibus vitae. Nulla vitae consequat tortor. Sed ornare, elit sit amet tempus tincidunt, leo arcu malesuada elit, iaculis aliquam neque tortor a nisi. Aliquam placerat faucibus tortor, et interdum massa tristique vitae. Maecenas commodo lobortis libero ac placerat. Nam tincidunt augue non sollicitudin iaculis. Etiam consectetur libero non neque varius efficitur. Maecenas id tortor ipsum.

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Phasellus ut quam et eros ullamcorper posuere nec vitae sapien. Cras id leo placerat, porttitor felis vel, accumsan mauris. Nullam eget mauris vitae libero tincidunt dictum non et sem. Integer ipsum orci, blandit sit amet porta sollicitudin, interdum id nisl. Duis ac nulla mauris. Fusce dictum porttitor dolor vel viverra. Integer tempus nisi sed enim semper tristique. Maecenas feugiat, lectus ac viverra semper, orci libero lobortis urna, placerat accumsan nulla quam non libero. Proin ex ante, vehicula quis aliquam id, consectetur efficitur orci. Quisque nisi quam, volutpat at convallis condimentum, sodales eget magna.

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These three values aren't *necessarily* the same, but they certainly *can be* the same, as they will be when the content doesn't have to scroll, vertical padding is zero, and there are no borders.

Comment: The content in my test scrolled.  No matter how much content I added the values were identical.  This was true for all browsers tested.