# How to increase height of textarea based font size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a textarea,where user will input some text,and also have a input range,where user can increase the font size of text,I want that the width of textarea still same,but height increase depend font size to show all text,and also I want textarea don't have a scroll and resize
I did that using div,and I want the same result using textarea

I did that using div  https://jsfiddle.net/Meline222/fgpedL0z/1/

I want the same result but using textarea https://jsfiddle.net/Meline222/fgpedL0z/3/ bt when i use textarea all text can't see

I tried did but all text don't show textarea

this work for div

```
 #inputText {
            width: 150px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow:hidden;
    resize: none;
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a textarea with auto-resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/454202/creating-a-textarea-with-auto-resize)

Comment: Isn’t div increasing its height along with the text inside?

Comment: your css works for me.

Comment: i have this https://jsfiddle.net/Meline222/fgpedL0z/1/ and i want the same result using textarea

Comment: but when I  use textarea https://jsfiddle.net/Meline222/fgpedL0z/3/ result not the same,I want increase height textarea to show all text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/craigiswayne/qkn8rdxp/20/

```js
function adjustSize(i){
    var o = document.getElementById('inputText');
    o.setAttribute("style","height: auto;");
    var val = i.value;
    o.style.fontSize = val + 'px';
    var fontSize = o.style.fontSize;
    o.setAttribute("style","font-size: " + fontSize + "; height: " + o.scrollHeight + "px;");  
}
```

```css
#inputText {
  width: 150px;
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="" id="inputText">kyb  u uuhhhkjh kj</textarea>
 <input id="input" type="range" min="12" max="72" oninput="adjustSize(this);">
```

---

So the solution I chose to set the `height` of the `textarea` to it's `scrollHeight`

---

`scrollHeight` is defined by MDN docs as

> The scrollHeight value is equal to the minimum height the element would require in order to fit all the content in the viewport without using a vertical scrollbar

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollHeight

---

see also this post for an explanation of `scrollHeight`, `clientHeight` and `offsetHeight`

[What is offsetHeight, clientHeight, scrollHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight)

Comment: Awesome  don't forget to make the answer as accepted

Comment: Can you say please why it doesn't work for the second textarea? https://jsfiddle.net/vpk81yr0/1/ when I click to choose font-size it doesn't work the same way,as a first textarea

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the height to be adjusted along font size, use `em` unit measure.

```
width: 150px;
height: 2em;
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Values_and_units) about the `em` unit says

> em: 1em is the same as the font-size of the current element.