# how to calculate document height and add width to div to it will show much page is left

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want to add width to my div by the how much page height is so it can show how much page is left if page scrolled to bottom div width should be 100% and if it at middle it should be half

```
window.onscroll = function () {
    addLoaderWidth();
}

function addLoaderWidth() {
    var addWidth = window.pageYOffset;
    document.getElementById('load').style.width = addWidth + 'px';

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by calculating the percentage that was scrolled down and use that value as the width of the element.

```js
const progress = document.getElementById('progress');
window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
  let d = document.documentElement, b = document.body;
  let percentage = (d.scrollTop||b.scrollTop) / ((d.scrollHeight||b.scrollHeight) - d.clientHeight) * 100;
  progress.style.width = percentage + '%';
});
```

```css
#progress {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 8px;
  width: 0%;
  background-color: #48E;
}
#content {
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="progress"></div>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: whats the difference between scroll height and client height

Comment: Here are some good write-ups about the differences: [What is offsetHeight, clientHeight, scrollHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22675126/1970822)(SO) or [Difference between offsetHeight, clientHeight and scrollHeight](https://medium.com/@jbbpatel94/difference-between-offsetheight-clientheight-and-scrollheight-cfea5c196937)(Ext)

Answer (score 2):

Your javascript works just fine. I had to add some style for the `#load` element, and add a container around the element that was scrollable. But it seems to work as expected:

```js
window.onscroll = function () {
    addLoaderWidth();
}

function addLoaderWidth() {
    var addWidth = window.pageYOffset;
    document.getElementById('load').style.width = addWidth + 'px';

}
```

```css
#load {
  height: 10px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .2s ease;
}

.container {
  height: 1000px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="load"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: if fill's the width before the page is ended