# UL tags causes unexpected clientHeight (or scrollHeight) in chrome

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not expecting **clientHeight** and **scrollHeight** to be different below. Is there something I'm not aware of. I can only guarantee they are different in chrome. Not sure what people are experiencing in different browsers.

Anytime I include a UL tag in chrome it throws the values off no matter where it's placed in the containing element being measured

**EDIT:** they are reporting as equal in Safari. So can I assume this is a bug or is Safari wrong?
**The margin padding etc, are the same in both browsers by default**

**This question is not about the difference between them, I'm getting different results in different browsers, and neither is what any other answer of documentation implies**

In Safari they are both 18px and in Chrome the scrollHeight is 34 and the clientHeight is 18

Shouldn't they both be 34px, or at least the same as they are in Safari as 18

Ty!

```js
console.log(document.body.clientHeight);
console.log(document.body.scrollHeight);
```

```html
<ul><li>test</li></ul>
```

Comment: Have a read here: https://medium.com/@jbbpatel94/difference-between-offsetheight-clientheight-and-scrollheight-cfea5c196937

Comment: I do know the difference between them. I just checked, they are reporting as equal in Safari

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is offsetHeight, clientHeight, scrollHeight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight)

Comment: Sorry no, I understand the difference between them very very well. I'm getting unexpected values, and different values based on which browser I'm using

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be that the margin-block default properties for `<ul>` (you don't need `<li>` inside) affect the scroll height. If you set margin-block to zero, you should see the same measurements.

Something interesting is that, inside this snippet, the sizes are still off by one pixel, but testing it on codepen shows the same number.

```js
console.log(document.body.clientHeight);
console.log(document.body.scrollHeight);
```

```css
ul {
      margin-block-end: 0;
      margin-block-start: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>test</li></ul>
```

Comment: I would expect them to be the same regardless of the margin on the ul tag

Comment: This is interesting, can you please give me more info on how those css properties would affect this

Comment: To be honest with you, I have never used these properties other than to set them to zero to avoid them affecting calculations. You can see more information about them on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-block-start . Chrome has some defaults for their elements.

Comment: This is the kind of info I was looking for :) because margins alone shouldn't have thrown off those calculations. I still think it's something unique to ULs thoughts. For instance, an H3 tag has similar settings but doesn't throw off any calculations

Comment: @rubixibuc for me, h3 does throw off calculations https://jsfiddle.net/49gmr2x3/

Comment: To the spec I would expect both values to be the same in these scenarios. Regardless of any of these values

Answer (score 0):

Browsers tend to give some default values for margin and padding, which varies sometimes, making design inconsistent among each other.

That's why developers tend to use this simple trick to reset them:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0
}
```

Now, if you added this to your CSS, you will find both `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` have a value of `18px`.

Comment: even with the default values, the margin inside the body seems to overflow it, and not be counted in chrome. I'm only seeing this with UL tags. In safari it's even stranger to me because it doesn't count the margin at all.