# Nuxt.js Scroll to bottom of div element

Tags: scroll, nuxt.js

What`s wrong with this code? After render div element scroll has to be in the bottom of div element. scrollTop not saving the value after func

```
<main>
<div v-if="messages">
   <ul ref="messagesContainer">
       <li v-for="message in messages" :key="`${message.text}.${message.username}`">
         <Message :message="message" :username="username" />
       </li>
   </ul>
</div>
</main>
```

```
 mounted() {
    this.scrollToEnd();
  },
  methods: {
    scrollToEnd() {
      const height = this.$refs.messagesContainer.scrollHeight;
      this.$refs.messagesContainer.scrollTo(0,height)
      // doesnt work 
      // this.$refs.messagesContainer.scrollTop = height
    }
  }
```

```
 main {
    background-color: #fff;
    height: 56vh;
    ul {
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      flex: auto;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<main>
   <ul v-if="messages" id="messagesContainer">
      <li v-for="message in messages" :key="`${message.text}.${message.username}`">
        <Message :message="message" :username="username" />
      </li>
   </ul>
</main>


scrollToEnd() {
  const element = document.getElementById('messagesContainer')
  element.scrollTop = element.offsetHeight + element.scrollHeight
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work on Nuxt. This also provides a smooth scrolling as well.

```
  const element = this.$refs.messagesContainer;
  element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start" });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the y position of the element via the `offsetHeight` property like this:
`var offsetTop = this.$refs.messagesContainer.offsetHeight;`

You can find more information regarding `offsetHeight`, `clientHeight` and `scrollHeight` properties [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675126/what-is-offsetheight-clientheight-scrollheight)

Note you need to call the `scrollTo` method on the `window` element:

example:

```
methods: {
    scrollToEnd() {
      var scrollHeight = this.$refs.messagesContainer.offsetHeight;
      this.$refs.messagesContainer.scrollTop = scrollHeight;
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: it doesn't help:(
I don`t know where is the problem

Comment: Is the window not scrolling at all? Can you try logging the  `offset` value? Is it possible that you are trying to scroll to the bottom of the element before the messages are loaded and the component fully rendered?

Comment: I'm not sure that I need to use window, because scrolling only available in this div element

Comment: Ahh okay I got you now. Then you need to set the `this.$refs.messagesContainer.scrollTop = this.$refs.messagesContainer.scrollHeight`. Will edit the answer above.

Comment: can you try binding this method on a button click and call it just to see if that it's not related to any time-related rendering problem?

Comment: ``console.log(scrollTop,scrollHeight);
this.$refs.messagesContainer.scrollTop =this.$refs.messagesContainer.scrollHeight;
console.log(scrollTop,.scrollHeight)``

same logs in both situations... scrollTop isn`t saving the value